# Javascript regex, match contains in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have done this regex yet.

```
[\<jobjob].*|\s*[jobjob\>]
```

I need to match  all these examples:

```
<jobjob fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
    <h1>fruit</h1>
}); jobjob>
```

```
<jobjob
fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
    <h1>fruit</h1>
});
jobjob>
```

```
<jobjobfruits.forEach((fruit) => {<h1>fruit</h1>});jobjob>
```

```
<jobjob fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
    <h1>fruit</h1>
}); jobjob>
```

```
<jobjob fruits.forEach((fruit) => { <h1>fruit</h1> }); jobjob>
```

I matched just last two and part of first two.

What I do wrong?

Comment: What are the differences between #1 and #4  and between #3 and #5?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? What exactly are you trying to do? Is that HTML? It seems to me like you're trying to do something that you shouldn't be using a regex for.

Comment: Try this `<jobjob[\S\s]*?jobjob>`

Comment: @sln Thanks dude. Do you explain me what `?` means in this regex, please?
@geekley I need regex. I try to create own syntaxe and own little parser. Small and simple project.
@PM77-1 The form of writing. You can also write HTML in a lot of ways and these ways do the same thing. You know.

Comment: Sure dude, the `?` means 0 or once. When it modifies a greedy quantifier `+` or `*` it makes it lazy so that the first matching `jobjob>` is found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `str.match(/<jobjob.*?jobjob>/s)`?

`/s` means that `.` matches also newlines

Comment: Javascript does not support 'singleline' : https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: Although regular-expressions.info page shouldn't be used as a reliable source, you are partly right.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2) says that `dotAll` is supported.

[ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.flags) - chapter 21.2.5.3 doesn't support it.

[Next version](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-notation) adds the missing support.

And it works in latest Chrome...

Comment: A lot of browsers don't support this. It needs to be for more users I cannot afford to it does not work for someone.